Discharger for 48V LiFePO4 batteries?
I have a pair of 48V 100Ah LiFePO4 batteries that I've removed from my boat for the winter.
They're currently at ~100% charge.
They'll be sitting in my basement over the winter, because my boat will be outside over a Minnesota winter, and lithium doesn't much care for -40° temps.
It's my understanding that it's better to store lithium at 50% than 100, but how do I bring the power down?
There are plenty of 12V devices I could plug in to just burn power. I could just plug in an inverter and then a space heater. But I don't have anything that runs on 48VDC except my electric outboards, and I can't run them out of the water.
I'm thinking all I'd need is a resistor. A 5Ω resistor between the terminals would give me about 10A and that would bring me down to 50% power in about five hours.
Would that be a terribly stupid idea?
I expect it would need a heat sink to dissipate the energy. In fact, when I look on Digikey, I find 5Ω/100W resistors that might suit my needs that seem to be mostly heat sink. Would they work, as-is? Or would I need to provide additional heat dissipation?
Should I inline a fuse? A switch? Or am I over-engineering this, and I just need to wire the resistor directly to the terminals?
Or does someone already sell this kind of thing, preassembled?

wire them in series and run a "110v" load to drain it, a  hotplate, tungsten bulb, space heater, etc.

I don't have a 48V inverter, and don't need one.

i mean directly from DC, resistive loads don't care about AC/DC and the voltage of a series pair is already about 110v. this lets you safely use common stuff (like light bulbs) you already have around.

An old-fashioned, stupid space heater might work. If there's modern electronics, not a chance.

Any switches on the devices will probably not be rated for DC operation.

@vir true, but you don't really even need to switch it on/off TBF.  cheap heaters are still made with basic analog components, as are irons, waffle makers, rice cookers and crock pots. a 500W "heat lamp bulb" would be perfect. cheap 12v headlights from a clearance rack in series would work as well. A resistor of any sort will get hot as hell and could be dangerous as it could melt the wire and fail closed; submerge it in oil or water if you go that route and do it outside, preferably on a driveway or gravel.

What about 4 × 12V halogen vehicle headlamp bulbs in series? At 150W each, that's 600W, no cooling required, maybe sunglasses though.

Why didn't you discharge them in the boat so you would not have this problem? Turn the accessories on and let it drain the batteries. The problem never happens.

Power dissipated in a resistor is V²/R. The open circuit voltage of a nominal 48V LiFePO4 battery could be pushing 60V at full charge, so a 5 ohm resistor would be dissipating almost 700W. You're in no hurry; I would use a 50 ohm 100 watt resistor that would draw an amp or so and dissipate 50-60 watts. It will still get extremely hot though so make sure it's not in contact with anything flammable. A fan wouldn't hurt either. I'm sure you could find a charger/maintainer with discharge capability, but this isn't the place for product recommendations.

For reference, 700W is roughly the heat output of a portable space heater on "low". Anything that can dissipate that without melting is not small.

The battery hold 5kWh, so anything that discharges it is going to either dump a lot of power or take a long time.

I've been bouncing around ideas. I've been considering electronic load testers, but on first look they seemed far more expensive than I would be willing to pay.
Then I found a MakerHawk Electronic Load Tester, for ~$50, which looks like it would work. Will work with voltages from 0V to 200V, and will dump a max of 185W. Which would drop the battery by 50% in 13 hours.
I think I'd still want a fuse inline, just in case.

+1 on the fuse. I really don't like push more than 100W through a TO-247. I think a $5 rice cooker from goodwill would be the safest bet under $150 as most energy goes into the water and once it dries out, power drops from ~300W to ~30W using the fail-safe currie temp of the magnetic switch latch. They are an ingenious design with really dumb components.

You can use a battery low voltage disconnect protector wired with a resistor as already mentioned and set the voltage to whatever you want. Then it would discharge the battery to your set value and then disconnect the resistor. The circuit would still draw a little current to keep it active but at least it will give you plenty of time to see when it's done and disconnect it. You might be able to wire the relay that is powering the resistor to also power the board so when it's done it kills power to the board too
Something like this should work.
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09ZTHRD3G/ref=sspa_mw_detail_0?ie=UTF8&psc=1&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9waG9uZV9kZXRhaWwp13NParams
I'd also use a light bulb instead of resistors as it will give you a visual indicator of when it's done and can tolerate the heat. Maybe four headlight bulbs in series for 48 V

LiFePO4 discharge curve is too flat for voltage to be much use in determining SOC.
